# Exit Function When Conditions Are Not Met - Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function

I'm attempting to write a function in Visual Basic that will run if certain criteria are met. If not, then the function will terminate.

Right now I have the following,

```
Function answer(list As range) As String

    Dim extent As Integer
    extent = list.rows.Value
    Dim array_1() As Double
    ReDim array_1(1 To extent) As Double
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To extent
        array_1(i) = list(i).value
        If array_1(i) <> "L" Or array_1(i) <> "R" Or array_1(i) <> "PD" Or array_1(i) <> "D" Or array_1(i) <> "PD" Or array_1(i) <> "P" Or array_1(i) <> "S" Then
            answer = "Your list is not valid"
            Exit Function
        End If
        Next i

    'Otherwise function will perform rest of code

    answer = "Your list is valid"

End Function
```

If my input is: `=answer(A1:A6)` for example...with lets say, `A1 = "XXX"` which does not equal "L" or "R" or "PD" etc. I expect my answer to be "Your list is not valid" but instead I get #VALUE!

It is not clear to me why this is the case.

Comment: `extent = list.rows.count`

Comment: @Soto have you tried my code in my answer below ? any feedback ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I have. Works like a charm! Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few modifications you need to make to your code:

1. In order for `extent` to have the number of rows in the Range, use `extent = list.rows.count`.
2. You don't need the array `array_1()` , look at point 3. (thanks to @nightcrawler23 for noticing)
3. You need to loop through your `list` (Range.Cells), and check each `cell.Value` if it doesn't contain any of your special characters (I used here the `Select Case` to simplify and shorten your code).

**Code** (Tested)

```
Function answer(list As Range) As String

    Dim extent As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    extent = list.Rows.Count

    ReDim array_1(1 To extent)

    For Each cell In list.Cells
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "L", "R", "PD", "D", "S"

            Case Else
                answer = "Your list is not valid"
                Exit Function

        End Select
    Next cell

    'Otherwise function will perform rest of code
    answer = "Your list is valid"

End Function
```

Comment: You don't need the array_1 at all. this would reduce much of the code.

Comment: Just use `Select Case cell.Value`

Comment: @nightcrawler23 thanks, you are right, I was using the original code, I didn't notice it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

or bypass the loop and use a one line `COUNTIF`:

*test*

```
Sub GetValues()
MsgBox Answer([A1:B10])
End Sub
```

*function*

```
Function Answer(list As Range) As Boolean
Answer = (Evaluate("Sum(COUNTIF(" & list.Address & ",{""L"",""R"",""PD"",""D"",""S""}))") = list.Cells.Count)
End Function
```